# Как приклеить подвал к низу экрана?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Как прилепить подвал именно к низу **экрана**, а не страницы, потому что я везде только и вижу, как все пишут, что для этого надо написать `margin-top: -50px;` но это опускает подвал только в самый низ **страницы**, а не **экрана**. А мне надо, если инфы мало, подвал был бы внизу, а как инфы уже больше, чем экран, то тогда уже по высоте **странице** двигался.

Как выглядит сейчас подвал:

[image]

CSS код футера:

```
#foot {
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 5px;
    clear: both;
    height: 35px;
    margin: -50px auto 0px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Если не получается вручную сделать, то попробуйте с помощью [генератора шаблонов][1]. Заодно, посмотрите, готовую разметку и CSS.

   [1]: http://csstemplater.com/

Comment: Попробовал, взял весь код футера, и заменил, тоже самое.

Comment: Очень сомневаюсь, что пробывали. Точнее, может код для футера и взяли, но только надо учитывать, что некоторые другие стили элементов, так же влияют на его положение. Выложите ваш код на http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Вот ссылка: [Как прижать футер (подвал) к низу](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/karkas-verstki/podval-k-nizu.html). Тут вроде то, что Вам нужно, с пояснениями и примером. Может поможет.

Comment: К выше сказанному могу посоветовать [csstemplater.com](http://csstemplater.com)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как прижимать footer всегда к низу экрана?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 3):

Конечно с запозданием, но вот Вам готовое решение:

```css
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>HEADER</header>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<footer>FOOTER</footer>
```

[Пример на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/qktyU/)

Answer (score 2):

`min-height` блоку с контентом ставили?

Как для примера:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
h1 {
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
}
#container {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#header {
    background: #ff0;
    padding: 10px;
}
#body {
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;   /* Высота футера*/
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px; /* Высота футера */;
    background: #6cf;
}
</style>

<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
#container
{
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="header"><h1>Заголовок</h1></div>
    <div id="body"><h1>Контент</h1></div>
    <div id="footer"><h1>Подвал</h1></div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Нет не ставил.

Comment: Ну так че попробуете?

Comment: Уже попробовал, теперь правило такое:


    #foot{
 margin: -35px auto 0;
 min-width: 1000px;
 height: 35px;
 background-color: green;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 5px;
 clear: both;
}

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте для body поставить минимальную высоту 100%, а для футера отрицательный маржин равный высоте самого футера.

Ну и еще по теме с хабра: [Прибитый к низу футер своими руками](http://habrahabr.ru/post/151320/)